# Saving image with PHP on localhost uploaded with a form

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to save an image uploaded with a HTML form on my localhost server (working with Xampp), but although there are no errors, the file isn't saved anywhere.
This is the form, really simple:

```
<form id="form1" action="result.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="imguploaded" id="imguploaded" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"></br>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" id="inputbtn" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
```

and this is the PHP code (on result.php):

```
<?php
    $result=false;
    $error=false;
    if (isset($_FILES['imguploaded'])){
        $nomefile = strtolower($_FILES['imguploaded']['name']);
        $path = "caricamenti/$nomefile";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imguploaded']['name'], $path);
        echo($path);
    }
    ?>
```

the path exists and it is in the same folder of the .PHP files.

Comment: $path = "caricamenti/".$nomefile; change like this and try

Comment: Thanks for answering, tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imguploaded']['tmp_name'], $path . '/' . $_FILES['imguploaded']['name');

Comment: when moving you need to move _from_ `tmp_name` to the new `$path`: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imguploaded']['tmp_name'], $path);`

Comment: you should sanitize the filename and check for allowed mimetypes before moving! I could now upload a php script and execute that...

Comment: Changed to tmp_name but it still isn't working. What do you mean with sanitize the filename? Could you link a documentation/article about that?

Comment: basicly checking for the extention to prevent the script from saving a `.php`, `.exe`,.. [pathname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is usefull for that.

Comment: can you be more precice with _"still isn't working"_? How far do you get? Hit the php script? Get into if-condition? What does `move_uploaded_file` return? Do you have a value for `$_FILES['imguploaded']['name']`? What does `var_dump($_FILES)` give you? All those debugging steps would be usefull to find the bug...

Answer (score 2):

In `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imguploaded']['name'], $path);` the first parameter isn't correct. It should be the temporary path where php stored it intermediatly, which you find in `$_FILE['imguploaded']['tmp_name']`.
So change that line to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imguploaded']['tmp_name'], $path);
```

relevant [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Be sure to:

- sanitize filename & extention first
- check for allowed mimetypes, size, ..

Right now I could easily upload a php script and execute that.

Comment: @LorenzoGnech Jeff is right. Accepting an answer tells everyone and the system that the question was solved. If you don't know how, you can ask.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $file_name= $_FILES['imguploaded']['name'];
 $file_tmp_name= $_FILES['imguploaded']['tmp_name'];
 $div= explode('.',$file_name );
 $file_txt= strtolower(end($div));
 $unique_image= substr(md5(time()),0,10).".".$file_txt;
 $uploaded_image= "caricamenti/".$unique_image;
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,$uploaded_image);
```

Comment: adding a bit more explanation than "Try this" could be helpfull.